# Openmp with tasks

Tags: c, task, openmp

I am trying to implement string matching with a Boyer-Moore algorithm in parallel, using C with OpenMP tasks. The problem is that I have a race condition but I can not detect it.

This part of the code is to split the base text to chunk and get results:

```
int chunks = 8;
int sizeText = (int) sizeB;
int start = sizeText/(chunks + 1);
int end = sizeText%(chunks + 1);
int j;

// inicio=cp_Wtime();
#pragma omp parallel
#pragma omp single
for (i=0;i<(argc-2);i++) {
    #pragma omp task firstprivate(i)
    {
        int patlen = (int) sizeS[i];
        int delta1[ALPHABET_LEN];
        int *delta2 = malloc(patlen * sizeof(int));

        #pragma omp task
        make_delta1(delta1, S[i], patlen);
        #pragma omp task
        make_delta2(delta2, S[i], patlen);
        #pragma omp taskwait

        results[i] = sizeText;
        for(j = 0; j < chunks; j++) {
            #pragma omp task firstprivate(j)
            {
                int result = boyer_moore(delta1, delta2, B+(start*j), (2 * start) + end, S[i], patlen);
                if(result > -1 && result < results[i]) {
                    //printf(" %d %d %d \n", j, result, start);
                    #pragma omp critical
                    results[i] = result + start*j;
                }
            }
        }
        #pragma omp taskwait
        if (results[i] == sizeText) results[i] = -1;
        //results[i] = boyer_moore(delta1, delta2, B, (int) sizeB, S[i], patlen);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please clarify some things to make it possible to answer your question. 1) What is a *career condition*?, 2) how did you observe it? 3) please provide a [mcve]!

Comment: I assume that career condition is a direct translation from 'condición de carrera', actually meaning 'race condition'

Comment: @RafaCarbonell There's a lot missing to this question. What is `results` ? And all those functions you call? Try to [make your example smaller](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).